# Insert/Delete/Insert results in tracking error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a console .NET Core 2.1 app that is using EF Core 2.1.  It talks to a Database to read and insert rows.  This database is also being updated by other applications at the same time.

The issues I run into is, I create a row from my console app, then an external app deletes this row, and then when I again try to insert the row with the same primary keys, I run into the exception below -

> The instance of entity type 'XYZ' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 11, ABC: 136, DEF: 97}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Below is my code

```
var entity = PopulateValuesFor(XYZ);

var existingXYZ = _Context.TABLE1
            .Include(r => r.TABLE2)
            .Include(r => r.TABLE3)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == 1234);                                 

        if (existingXYZ == null)
        {
            _Context.Add(entity);
        }
```

The flow is

1. Above code is called  --> row is instered
2. External app deletes the row from data
3. Above code is called again --> exception

How do I tell the DbContext that the entity is no longer in the database... flush out your entries and add this row to the database again?  Because it's a console app, only 1 instance of DbContext is being used, which get's injected into the class implementing this method.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve]. We need the complete code to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a long lived static context. I would suggest wrapping the above in a using statement and going for a short lived context. That way your context wont think its inserted entity already.

Comment: I am creating an instance of services.AddDbContext in StartUp.cs class (yes, I still have this in the console app) so that it gets injected. If I have to create a short lived context, where would I be creating the DbContext?

Comment: Create it around the transactional boundaries of where you are using it. Instead of injecting the context inject a context factory. A context living for a long time is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I did not create a context factory, but just ended up creating a new context before each DB operation.  This solved the issue.  Also I moved the DbContextOptionsBuilder options builder to the OnConfiguring method in the Context class and took it off from the startup.  This way, I don't have to worry about Context being injected as a service.